# Lorenz - why is the solution with noise in initial condition on the same curve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I want to use Lorenz'63 for the purpose of testing some algorithms I'm currently researching.

When I defined a system and solved it in Matlab, plot of x-coordinates for explicit and perturbed initial conditions looked like this:

[image: x-coordinate for both solutions]

Obviously, there's a big difference in values. But, when I plotted the two solutions $3D$, I got this plot:

[image: Green solution is with explicit, and magenta solution is with perturbed initial conditions]

Apparently, both solutions lie on the same curve. How is this possible? I would really appreciate any explanation or, even better, some sources from where I can read more about this and get a better feeling of what I'm dealing with.

I tried to find this information in some papers but I couldn't find the explanation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your first plot is a time plot. It shows that for two solutions with $x$-coordinates $x_1, x_2$, the quantity   $|x_1(t) - x_2(t)|$ can be very large for sufficiently large $t$, even if $x_1(0) - x_2(0)|$ are very small. Your second plot shows two orbits, without showing the dependence on $t$. Thus if two solutions appear close, this  may be for different times $t$.

Comment: It's not too surprising that both solutions are attracted to the Lorentz *attractor*, is it?